# Dynamic Button creation

Tags: java, android, button, dynamic

Can anyone help me out here I need to create a dynamic ImageButton but I can not get seem to even get this regular button to work, I'm getting an error on this line `ll.addView(button,param);`

```
package org.iimed.www;    
import org.iimed.www.R.layout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class Penicillins extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ImageButton back,addmed;
    Context adaba;
    Drawable mmimed;

    public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.penicillin);
        back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back);
        addmed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addmed);
        back.setOnClickListener(this);
        addmed.setOnClickListener(this); 
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.back:
            startActivity(new Intent(
                Penicillins.this, ImageTextListViewActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.addmed:
            RelativeLayout ll=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.sundayopen);
            setContentView(R.layout.sundayopen);

            Button button= new Button (this);
            LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            ll.addView(button,param);
        }
    }
```

error:

```
01-07 18:49:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(27389): at org.iimed.www.Penicillins.onClick(Penicillins.java:63)
```

Comment: Well, what is the error? Add it to your original question.

Comment: my guess would be that ll is null, but you'll need to show us the error from log cat, if your not sure how a quick google search will show you.

Comment: @ToeKnee please see my answer. It will help you. :)

Comment: @superuser Trying this now, thank you. Sorry for delay guys I stepped away from the pc, I will post the logcat now but even in the stacktrace it is a single line error with no other info just 'org.iimed.wwww.penicillins java error:52

Comment: @ToeKnee thats fine. I hope I can help!

Comment: @superuser it is still giving me an error on this line ll.addView(button); with your edit.

Comment: 01-07 18:49:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(27389):  at org.iimed.www.Penicillins.onClick(Penicillins.java:63)

Comment: It seems to me that the error is on the "ll" being null, I am choosing to create the button on the relevant layout sundayopen is there something I need to do in the sundayopen.java or layout to account for this new button?

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
            Button button= new Button (this);
            LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


            ll.addView(button,param);
```

to

```
            Button button= new Button (this);
            LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            button.setLayoutParams(param);


            ll.addView(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` instead of `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`

and **remove** this `setContentView(R.layout.sundayopen);` line.

As this makes no sense here.

At last put  `break;` after `ll.addView(button,param);`

Try Change

```
LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

**To**

```
RelativeLayout param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: Still an error on this line ll.addView(button,param); been at it for days and I can't get it..thanks a lot anyhow.

Comment: @ToeKnee can you post your layout?

Comment: @ToeKnee RelativeLayout ll=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.sundayopen); this relative layout is in penicillin layout or in other layout?

Comment: @ Amit Gupta another layout, it's the xml page I'm wanting the button to create on.

Comment: @ToeKnee Button can be added in your main layout only. So declare RelativeLayout in your main layout with no child and try again.

Comment: So I can't generate a button on a different layout? I don't know in what context you mean"So declare RelativeLayout in your main layout with no child and try again" sorry I'm very new.